# KeyError when using .loc method using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, data-analysis

I have a simple project that I  have created using the information that I collected from an excel sheet file (xlsx file).

> this is the information I am working with

[image]

when I run `df.iloc[1]`
the output is

[image]

but when I run `df.loc['Amazon']`  I get a KeyError for the keyword I am looking for

[image]

I have looked into the documentation in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and noticed the same syntax as I used in the code below. I am not sure if there has to be other requirements for me to run this particular code.

Am I required to use a specific type of file for this to function properly or am missing a simple syntax in my code?

Comment: Amazon is in the Name column and is not a key. You could do `df[df["Name"]=="Amazon"]`

Comment: Check pandas library documentation please . You should try: `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Amazon']`

Comment: thank you both, I was able to get it to function properly, however I looked at the documentation and noticed that the same code I used previously was in the doc section but it was incorrect https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the "Name" column as the index of the DataFrame first.

```py
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
// then you can use the cell value of the "Name" column to index
df.loc['Amazon']
```

Ref: [pandas.DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: is '''df.loc[df['Name'] == 'CVS Health']''' the same as the code above?

Comment: It seems yes (or to be clearer `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Amazon']`). But the difference is that if you index the "Name" column multiple times, using this long expression may be time-consuming. So it will be better to set it as index first.

Comment: Understood. thank you for the clarification, I realized that the syntax I was using was for an older version of Pandas which is no longer supported unless I download that version onto my PC